# Populate choice field from model

Tags: wagtail

I'm aware that there is a Google Groups Wagtail support case with [exactly the same title](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wagtail/TP8WAQpenlc) - but I don't get it.

I want to populate a Choice (?) on page A (`class EventPage(Page)`) with data from page B (`class SpeakerPage(Page)`); in order to let the user choose the (there could only be one) speaker for an event.

What I tried till now:

```
class SpeakerPage(Page):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s' % (self.lastname, self.firstname)

    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ...


class EventPage(Page):
    speaker = models.ForeignKey('SpeakerPage', 
            related_name='+', 
            null=True, blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('speaker'),
    ]
```

And I got a dropdown-menu on `EventPage` - but this menu is empty. How do I get the speakers in there?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the noise - the dropdown-menue for the `ForeignKey` is working as expected. Just the `__unicode__` function did not achive the desired (formatted) result. 
A small modification did it:

`def __str__(self):
            return '%s, %s' % (self.lastname, self.firstname)`

Comment: In general, `__unicode__` is only required for python2, and `__str__` is what is to be used in python3, right?